# Referencing the creator of a page blog (the connected user) in my entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an entity for my accessing my pages (pages of a blog).

Here it is:

```
public class Page 
{
    [Key]
    public int PageId { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorName")]
    public virtual MembershipUser Author { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I would like to keep a reference to the person who created the page (in fact this is the connected user). So I defined an Author member in my class (of type MembershipUser). I also try to define the foreign key but **it doesn't work because there is no primary key in the MembershipUser entity**. I cannot add one to this entity because if is an aspnet object.

How can I proceed in order to have a reference to the creator of the page in my Page entity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the `MembershipUser` by creating a `CustomMembershipUser` that will inherit from `MembershipUser`.

You can add any fields you want to your `CustomMembershipUser`, you will then also have to create a table of your own with both the original fields and your extra fields.

[Here is some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx) that describes how you can do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I prefer to avoid this solution. If possible, I really would like to simply keep the asp.net Membership provider. Because I don't have to add more fields, I simply would like to keep a reference between my 'page entity' and a user.

Comment: If you extend the MembershipUser you can still use all the infrastructure that ASP.NET provides! You can also add the new entity (in the table you created) to your model so you can have navigational properties to it.

Answer (score 0):

What ORM are you using?

Anyway, you won't be able to reference a class that is not mapped in your ORM. You could create an entity like `SystemUser`, map it to a table and reference it at your `Page` entity. When you log in using `Membership`, you could query that `SystemUser` and store it in `HttpSession` so you can use it later.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework. Ok, so "you won't be able to reference a class that is not mapped in your ORM". I think I'll simply add a member of type string and store the username in it. So there will be no link between my page and my user.